# Is it possible for an SoC to have a built-in SSD?

Tags: asic, solid-state-devices, system-on-chip, ssd

Is it possible to have an SoC that includes an SSD on-chip, or are there technical constraints that prevent that? What are those technical constraints, if any?

Comment: Yes But you need the drivers for SSD.

Comment: It's very common for SoCs to have embedded flash memory, but usually only a small amount for cost reasons.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense as long as you don't specify the size of SSD.

Answer (score 3):

From a technical standpoint, an SoC can contain flash memory, either as a multi-die module, or with an embedded-flash silicon process ([example](https://www.tsmc.com/english/dedicatedFoundry/technology/specialty/eflash)).

However, while this is flash memory and serves a similar functional purpose, it's somewhat different from a real SSD (solid-state *drive*) as far as capacity and performance. Unlike an SoC, a solid-state drive typically has space for multiple dedicated flash dies (made on a silicon process optimized for flash), a separate controller with DRAM, etc. An SoC needs to fit this memory on the chip, so it's much smaller (e.g. enough for a bootloader/program/small operating system) and likely not as performant.

From a quick glance, TSMC reports eFlash capacities [on the order of 32-128 MiB](https://www.tsmc.com/english/dedicatedFoundry/technology/platform-automotive-tech-NVM) for such an embedded process. A die-stacked flash chip could probably do better, but it would still look and feel more like a small flash chip than a highly-performant SSD.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion that there is a fundamental physics dichotomy between a good logic process and a good storage process.

You want to minimise signal delays in logic circuitry; that implies lowering routing capacitance as far as possible, or low-K dielectric. Some level of leakage current is tolerable as a tradeoff for faster switching.

Storage, whether DRAM or Flash EPROM, requires storing enough charge to retain a bit of data, in the smallest possible area. That implies the highest possible capacitance per unit area, or a high K dielectric. And leakage current is the enemy.

(Unless the bit is stored magnetically, or via ferroelectric effect, or optically, all of which pose other material problems)

So a good logic process needs a large chip area per bit, which will make it highly uncompetitive for an SSD, while a good storage process will have difficulty implementing any high speed logic more complex than a memory interface.

If you need both fast logic and efficient storage, you really want two separate processes.